# Docker Status Exited (127) on Mac

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to setup a simple Python Flask server on a Docker container (on Mac OS) as per the first example in this link:

https://towardsdatascience.com/docker-made-easy-for-data-scientists-b32efbc23165

Both the image and containers are getting created without any errors but container status shows as Exited (127):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
f029880cbc35        126e05e474ef        "/bin/sh -c ['python…"   7 seconds ago       Exited (127) 6 seconds ago                       epic_williams
```

I have checked the End of Line character and it is LF for Docker, main.py and requirements.txt.

Below is the Docker file for reference:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ['python']
CMD ['main.py']
```

Could someone please provide inputs on what could be causing this? Thank you.

**Update 1**

Ran it twice as per  moctarjallo suggestion and here is the output.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
33f10ec30c8d        126e05e474ef        "/bin/sh -c ['python…"   5 seconds ago       Exited (127) 4 seconds ago                        great_hamilton
f029880cbc35        126e05e474ef        "/bin/sh -c ['python…"   52 minutes ago      Exited (127) 52 minutes ago                       epic_williams
```

Comment: try reruning the image

Comment: Just tried it...both of them are showing up as Exited

Comment: Can you please post the content of the requirements.txt file?  It looks like the tutorial you linked does not have a step to install flask.

Comment: Flask==1.0.2...this is what I have in the requirements.txt file

Comment: Try `ENTRYPOINT ['python', 'main.py']` without CMD (or the same in CMD without ENTRYPOINT - see [here](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) for differences). Also, you might need to put absolute path for python (maybe `/usr/bin/python` - depends on setup)

Comment: You can execute `docker logs 33f10` to see what happened when it was up.

Comment: Urban...entry point change doesn't work...Python is recognised as it is without the absolute path in terminal

Comment: Mike...bin/sh: 1: [python,: not found...this is what I get for logs

Comment: Urban..the change to absolute path for Python doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you are using single quotes  Please try `["python"]` and `["main.py"]` in your `Dockerfile`.  You will need to rerun `docker build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Docker `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` (and `RUN`) lines must be valid JSON arrays, obeying all of JSON's syntax rules, *including double quotes `"` around words*.  If not then Docker will silently interpret them as shell commands instead.

You probably want to just combine these into a single `CMD` line, *using double quotes*:

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

As you have it, since the single quotes aren't valid JSON, Docker separately wraps the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` strings in a `sh -c` wrapper, and then concatenates them together.  That leads to the odd command string you see in the `docker ps` output, and running it leads to the error you get.